# Unit Roots For Dummies book?

Tags: time-series, references, unit-root

After reading the intuitive explanation of unit roots by Whuber on this website, I am motivated to find out more about them.

What book would people recommend that gives a clear explanation of all the implications and details of unit roots, and can include a little simple maths, but not too much maths. In other words, books that are nearly all narrative.

I particularly want to avoid the kinds of books that for example show more than one line of maths at a time.

Comment: I doubt you will find an entire book on the topic. The topic is quite narrow, so if there is a book on it, it must go pretty deep (meaning multiple lines of math at a time).

Comment: @RichardHardy There is in fact a recent book by In Choi called “Almost All About Unit Roots”. I haven’t yet read it myself; if anyone has or does so I’d be interested in hearing if it’s any good.